# Day and month comparison without inluding year in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime, comparison

Given following information

```
orderdate=05/01/2016
startday=24
startmonth=08
endday=2
endmonth=10
```

Basically we have to compare orderdate for sales period that is `24 august` to `10 october`.

Dates falling outside the period of `24 august` to `10 october` will be non sales period.

So for any given order date we have to calculate whether it is falling in sales period or non sales period. The problem is that we are not provided with the year only start day ,start month,end day and end month.

Also lets say if we use Date time then for `start date=24/08/2016` and `enddate=2/10/2016`. It will take current year but normally it is wrong.

It should take `startdate=24/08/2015` (As non sales period will start from 3rd october 2015 till 23 August 2016 after that sales period will start and `enddate=2/10/2016` (which we are getting correct).

Please tell me if there is any possibility to compare only month and dates without year to compare orderdate with given  start day ,start month,end day and end month.

Comment: DateTime class has everything that you want, with nice naming somemore.. Check out its `Month` and `Day`.. and everything else it has!

Comment: how to display start date 24/08/2016 to Aug 24,if both start date and end date same display OneDay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work, but your question is not very clear.

```
Private Function InSalesPeriod(OrderDate As DateTime) As Boolean
    Dim salesStrt As New DateTime(OrderDate.Year, 8, 24)
    Dim salesEnd As New DateTime(OrderDate.Year, 10, 10)

    If OrderDate >= salesStrt AndAlso OrderDate <= salesEnd Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

This checks that the order date was between the dates given for the year of the order.

Comment: That's what I started with but (apparently) the order date can be after the sales period, so it might be in the previous year!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is the following. It creates a date based on the month and day supplied and then adjusts them to find historic dates that are chronologically correct:

```
    Private Function IsOrderInSalesPeriod(orderDate As Date, startMonth As Integer, startDay As Integer, endMonth As Integer, endDay As Integer) As Boolean

    Dim salesStartDate As New Date(DateTime.Now.Year, startMonth, startDay)
    Dim salesEndDate As New Date(DateTime.Now.Year, endMonth, endDay)
    'if the sales period is in the future it must be a year ahead
    If salesStartDate > DateTime.Now Then salesStartDate = salesStartDate.AddYears(-1)
    If salesEndDate > DateTime.Now Then salesEndDate = salesEndDate.AddYears(-1)
    'check that the start is before the end
    If salesStartDate > salesEndDate Then salesStartDate = salesStartDate.AddYears(-1)

    If orderDate >= salesStartDate AndAlso orderDate <= salesEndDate Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for giving the solution but in this scenario I am having only month and day.
According to your given line of code Dim salesStartDate As New Date(orderDate.Year, 8, 24) 
It will give the current year 2016 As 24 August 2016.For Example OrderDate = 5 jan 2016.
Now I have to check if it is falling between 1 november to 24 december (i.e sales period) or
 it is falling between 25 december to 31 october(non sales period).

Comment: Also using datetime will append current year.We have scenario when 25 december 2015 to 31 october 2016
(here start date has year  different copared to end date for non sales period).
It depends in which year we are calculating,Want a general solution so
 that it is applicable in all the scenarios.For Sales period it can
 work but for non sales period (from 25 dec to next years 31st october) it wont work.

Comment: Orderdate 1/01/2016, Condition for Non Sales Period( Startdate=25, Startmonth=12,Enddate=31, Endmonth=10).Now if we want to check for non sales period for current scenario it should be 25/12/2015 to 31/10/2016.But using date time it will give Startdate= 25/12/2016 ,Enddate= 31/12/2016.How start date can come after end date.

Comment: Ok I think I see what you mean now. I have edited my answer

Comment: Currently I am having two scenarios.When sales period is in diferent year. For Examlple Startdate=25, Startmonth=12,Enddate=2, Endmonth=2).And OrderDate=1/1/2016(Means my sale period is from 1 nov 2015 to 2 feb 2016)